# grant all privileges of all tables in database to a user

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-12c, permissions

I use oracle 12c. I try to grant all privileges of all tables to a user. And in future I don't need to add any privileges to that user. I need to do this. I don't want to grant system tables to that user. I wrote pl/sql command. but it gives error.

```
BEGIN
  2  FOR t IN (select * from dba_tables where owner not like '%SYS%' AND owner not like '%ADMIN%' AND iot_type IS NULL)
  3  LOOP
  4  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON '|| t.owner ||'.' || t.table_name ||' TO GGSTEST';
  5  END LOOP;
  6  END;
  7  /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

What is the mistake? thanks.

I use dbms_print

```
GRANT ALL ON OUTLN.OL$ TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON OUTLN.OL$HINTS TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON OUTLN.OL$NODES TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON DBSNMP.BSLN_BASELINES TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_LOG_HISTORY TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON DBSNMP.BSLN_METRIC_DEFAULTS TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$ROOT_INFO TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$XDB_READY TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$CDBPORTS TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$IMPORT_TT_INFO TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$TTSET TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$H_INDEX TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$D_LINK TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$COLUMN_INFO TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$PATH_INDEX_PARAMS TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.X$NM7UJB7VOLFE92KV0GUML7K0LVSF TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.X$QN7UJB7VOLFE92KV0GUML7K0LVSF TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.X$PT7UJB7VOLFE92KV0GUML7K0LVSF TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.APP_USERS_AND_ROLES TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.APP_ROLE_MEMBERSHIP TO GGSTEST
GRANT ALL ON XDB.XDB$DBFS_VIRTUAL_FOLDER TO GGSTEST
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Comment: Try adding double quotes to the owner and table name.

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON "'|| t.owner ||'"."' || t.table_name ||'" TO GGSTEST';

Comment: GRANT ALL ON IX.AQ$_STREAMS_QUEUE_TABLE_L TO GGSTEST; it is not error. But pl/sql, loop; it gives error.

Comment: then try this : GRANT ALL ON IX."AQ$_STREAMS_QUEUE_TABLE_L" TO GGSTEST

If it doesn't work, it may be something with the Advanced Queue feature...

Comment: What's the type of the object? 
    select OBJECT_TYPE, STATUS From dba_objects where owner = 'IX' and object_name = 'AQ$_STREAMS_QUEUE_TABLE_L'

Comment: I tried it's worked. Status type = TABLE and status = VALID

Comment: I change and it's worked.... FOR t IN (select * from dba_tables where owner!='GGSTEST' AND owner not like '%SYS%' AND owner not like '%ORDDATA%' AND owner not like '%ADMIN%' AND owner not like '%APEX%' AND owner not like '%XDB%' AND owner not like '%FLOW_FILES%'  AND owner not like '%OE%' AND iot_type IS NULL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ....` is MySQL privs syntax.

You need to do:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA.TABLE TO USER
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603).

Comment: Hi, I taught it was a MySQL Syntax too, but : [check this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm)

Comment: `grant all privileges to USERNAME` is completely different, and is a db-wide thing.

Comment: There is a section entitled "Granting Object Privileges on a Table to a User: Example"

Comment: Actually, god knows. Don't have a DB handy to test :/

Comment: It gives same error..

Comment: I change for statement and it's worked. thanks..

Answer (score 2):

It is the right command. Previously, it give error because of oracle's installation tables.

```
BEGIN
    FOR t IN (select * from dba_tables where owner!='GGSTEST' AND owner not like '%SYS%' AND owner not like '%ORDDATA%' AND owner not like '%ADMIN%' AND owner not like '%APEX%' AND owner not like '%XDB%' AND owner not like '%FLOW_FILES%' AND owner not like '%OE%' AND iot_type IS NULL)
    LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON '|| t.owner ||'.' || t.table_name ||' TO GGSTEST';
    END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is due to characters being interpreted by PL/SQL, like the dollar sign or the hash tag.
By adding double quotes, you won't get the error anymore.

Regards.

Comment: maybe hash. it doesn't give error with Dollar sign.

Comment: I exclude APEX, XDB, FLOW_FILES, ORDDATA schemas and it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to grant all privileges of all tables to a user.

Why?

> And in future I don't need to add any privileges to that user.

Yes, you will.
As soon as you add another table, you have to repeat the whole process *and* you have to do so for each and every User.  I would suggest that this is not an efficient use of your time.

> I need to do this.

We'll agree to disagree.

The *vast* majority of Users don't need (or want) "all privileges" on any table; select, insert, delete and update is all they need and all they should be given.
How are you going to explain to your Management how a Production system went down (for however long it takes *you* to recover it) because some User, somewhere, decided to drop a table, just because they discovered that they could?  That's *not* a User's responsibility, so they *shouldn't* have the permission to it in the first place.

Read up on Roles.
Grant object-level privileges to a Role, then grant that Role to [many] Users.  When you modify tables, you only have to [re-]grant privileges to the relevant Role(s); Oracle will take care of "cascading" those privileges to the relevant Users. 
If you need different "levels" of privilege for different groups of Users, create multiple Roles.

Comment: While these may be true things, he never gives information on if the schema is changing, if the env is dev or production, and if it's for a personal project or his company. You never address his actual syntax related problem.